# ASP.NET MVC: Passing several objects to the view including a validation model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, models, viewdata

I like using Models for validation

```
<!-- ViewPage -->

<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<TopicModel>" %>

...

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %>

...

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description) %>


// Controller

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTopic(TopicModel model)
{
     // validate
}
```

It works great, but when I need to pass additional data, I need to create a new ViewModel class and I loose the flexibility.

```
<!-- ViewPage -->

<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<TopicViewModel>" %>

<%= Model.SomethingImportant %>

...

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TopicModel.Title) %> // UGLY, I get name="TopicViewModel.TopicModel.Title"

...

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TopicModel.Description) %> // UGLY, same thing


// Controller

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTopic(TopicViewModel model)
{
     // validate
     var validationModel = model.TopicModel; // UGLY
}
```

How can I make it easier and better looking?

Comment: What flexibility do you lose by creating a view model? Why do you consider it ugly to have `name="TopicModel.Title"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the ViewData dictionary for your additional data outside of the model?

**Update** Alternatively, make your view model a subclass of your model and add the extra properties, but retain the validation of the base class.

Comment: That means I would have to cast objects which is not a good way of doing ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Then you could make your view model a subclass of your model and add the extra properties, but retain the validation of the base class.

Comment: Thanks! Not it works great. Very easy solution. (Please update your comment so other people can see how this problem was solved.)

Answer (score 1):

Your second example, which you say looks ugly, is actually a better way to do things than using ViewData.

The idea of a model is that it contains the "stuff" the view needs when it renders - so it is the perfect place to put all the data items the view needs.

If you are really offended by the naming convention (which is used by the framework to re-populate your model from a form post) you could flatten the model. This would give you "pretty" names for each item, but would be a lot of work for no reason.

Comment: What does it mean, "to flatten the model" ?